# blogger api post image

Tags: java, image, api, blogger

I'm trying to add a post with an image using java api. As the documentation describes (https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts) we can have an image with a URL. Running the following code didn't help:
        Post content = new Post();
        content.setTitle(...);
        content.setContent(...);

```
    List<Images> images=new ArrayList<Images>();
    for (PostAttachment attachment : attachmentsList) {
            Images img=new Post.Images();
            String imageUrl="http://amazon.com/mybucket/example.jpg";
            img.setUrl(imageUrl);
            images.add(img);

        }
        content.setImages(images);
    }
    // The request action.
    Insert postsInsertAction = blogger.posts()
            .insert(userId(), content);
```

- can we post with a URL that has external image link (http://s3.amazon.com/abc.jpg for example?)

BTW, i saw that we need upload images to picassaweb (link please?)  . don't know if they are still relevant.

Thanks,
   Fredy

Answer (score 2):

I am working with the Blogger API right now and had the same issue with python, the codesample google offered to post an Image doesnt work.

You have to add the image via html img-tag into your content.

Thats how it worked for Python but should be similar with Java:

```
request = posts.insert(blogId=your_blog_id, body = {"title" : "content title", "content" : "some text ... <img src = 'http://amazon.com/mybucket/example.jpg' title = 'test' alt = 'test' style='width:304px;height:228px;'>"}).execute()
```